# Navigation Toggler Collapse Not Working after Converting Bootstrap Template to Wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello im trying to convert direcly from HTML bootstrap template, to Wordpress template. But the toogler navigation not visible when viewed in mobile/responsive view. In HTML view my code is working as well.

What I have tried:

1. Compared the code to a theme I made as exercise and it looks exactly the same.
2. Pasted the navbar example from bootstrap directly and tested into HTML Template (working) but in the wordpress is not working (didn't collapse either)

Here my `function.php` file

```
<?php

function awesome_script_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_style ('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_register_style( 'Font_Awesome', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran');
    wp_enqueue_style('Font_Awesome');


    wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', null, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');

    wp_register_script( 'Bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', null, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('Bootstrap');

    wp_register_script( 'Popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', null, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('Popper');

    wp_register_script( 'Slim', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js', null, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('Slim');




}
```

And this is my `header.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Title</title>
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<section id="heroku">
<header id="bg-hero">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparan">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title </a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

    </ul>
    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active uppercase-pad">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item uppercase-pad">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item uppercase-pad">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item uppercase-pad">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your console in debugger for errors - I bet you get some! Also use wp_register_script() only when you're registering scripts and want to use them later in some specific cases ! My guess before you share the debugging is that this may be the cause of your trouble:

```
wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
```

You're registering jquery migrate and enqueue it simply as 'jQuery', try to change the name to smth. like 'jQuery-migrate', I assume its duplication of names and your jQuery is actually not beeng loaded.